# ServiceNow - create custom JSON web service

Tags: json, servicenow

I'm developing a mobile app that displays a list of projects, tasks and subtasks. It is important that I can get all the records in one call to SN
for example:

```
{"records":[
  {  ....
    "name": "Project One",
    "parent_tasks": [....
      "short_description": "Parent task 1"
      "subtasks": [
         "short_description":"Subtask 1.1"
      ]
    ]
  }

]}
```

so I decided to build my own web service that will generate a JSON response. As far as I know scripted web services can produce only WSDL, is there any way to get data in JSON format? 
I also tried to create Database View, but it seems like it is not possible to get all the info I need in one view.

What would be the best approach generate required data in JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to consider creating a processor. The following post offers some guidance. http://www.john-james-andersen.com/blog/service-now/create-your-own-rest-based-servicenow-web-service.html

Currently scripted web services in ServiceNow only support SOAP.

Curious about your requirement that "It is important that I can get all the records in one call to SN for example". Why do you need all this data returned in a single response?

Comment: Looks like it is the only way to go with the processor. I'm building a mobile app and it has to display projects+taks in a single view, so thats why I need it in a single response